# Botón que abra word existente y sustituye palabras especificas desde visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

tengo que realizar un proyectó desde Visual Studio con 3 botones.

- Botón que me abra un Word en blanco.
- Botón que abra Word existente.
- Botón que abra un Word existente pero reemplacé del texto unas palabras especificas que tengo entre llaves"{}"

Los 2 primeros los tengo. Es fácil.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        //abre word vacio
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("winword.exe");
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //abre word existente. la idea es ke el boton 3 ya me lo saque con los datos cambiados.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\angel.garcia\Documents\doc\nora\20210810\PRUEBADEPEDRO2COPIA.doc");
    }
}
```

Pero el tercero no sé cómo llamar al texto y que busque y reemplace.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en Español Legna. Esto que intentas hacer lo deberías hacer con una librería especifica de Office y no abrir el archivo con un Process.Start, ya que haciendo eso no cargas el documento en el programa, sino que ejecutas un proceso independiente a él. Investiga a cerca de la librería `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` para poder conseguir lo que buscas.

Comment: gracias fue lo que hice cree desde cero y tirando de interop todo perfecto.